# How do I change my username on Zoom, on my iPhone, without logging into Zoom?

Tags: iphone, zoom.app

I need to change my username in Zoom.  It's incorrect.  I can't log in because I don't have a zoom account.  All instructions I can find on the Zoom website or on other sites (which seem to have scraped Zoom for instructions) require you to log in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have to be in a meeting in order to change your username, if you don't have a Zoom account.

1. Join a meeting.  (You may need a friend to schedule one for you)
2. Click on/touch Participants
3. Click on/touch yourself
4. Click on/touch "rename"
5. Type the new name
6. Click done, leave, &tc to close the windows and leave the meeting